# Swiftui : Is there any better way to implement single and multi selection item than my way?

Tags: enums, swiftui, selection

the below code is the logic of multi and single selection. The way I did it was set up some array and just append element(s) into it by onTapGesture.
My question is, is this implementation is acceptable? Else, is there any better way to do it?

Thank you

```
enum IconSelection {
    case single, multi
}

    @State var blocks: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3,4]
    @State var selections: [Int] = []
    @State var enumSelected : IconSelection = .single
...

ScrollView(.horizontal){
    HStack {
        ForEach(self.blocks, id: \.self) { i in
            VStack {
                Block(id: i, isSelected: self.selections.contains(i), enumSelected: $enumSelected)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        switch enumSelected {
                        case .single :
                            if self.selections.count >= 1 {
                                self.selections.removeAll()
                                self.selections.append(i)
                            } else {
                                self.selections.append(i)
                            }
                        case .multi :
                            if self.selections.contains(i) {
                                self.selections.removeAll(where: { $0 == i })
                            } else {
                                self.selections.append(i)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 10)
            }
            .animation(.spring())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on many things. What is your use case? can the `blocks` array have duplicates? If so, this is a bad implementation because it uses `removeAll` you need an `Identifiable` quality. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238064/how-can-my-selection-go-right-in-the-list-i-created-in-swiftui/65239350#65239350 The link as a sample using the `index` or a `Dictionary` if you want to set up your own Icon model you could have a `var isSelected: Bool` and `filter` the array of icons.

Comment: Thank you @Iorem, the blocks are unique therefore it won't be duplicates

Comment: Generally, questions phrased *"Is there any better way"* are off-topic here. In my opinion this question should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com as you already have working code.